# How to print all tf.Tensors of a model in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tensorflow

I have the list of all tensors in my model which had the `float32` type:

```
import os                                                                                                     
import os.path
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename = 'MY_pb_file.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _= tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')
from pprint import pprint
    pprint([out for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.type != 'Placeholder' for out in op.values() if out.dtype == tf.float32])
```

which gives me all the list:

```
<tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/add:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/Rsqrt:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul_1:0' shape=(?, 64, 64, 16) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul_2:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/sub:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/add_1:0' shape=(?, 64, 64, 16) dtype=float32>,
...
```

At this point I can use `sess.run('NAME')` to see its value:

```
>>> sess.run('MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul:0')
array([  0.51656026,  29.6620369 ,   0.48722425,   7.73186255,
        -9.51173401,   0.60846734,   0.21111809,   0.23865609,
        23.85105324,   1.04134226,  28.59620476,  35.79195023,
         0.34110394,   0.5557093 ,  10.39805031,  10.99952412], dtype=float32)
```

However, I would like print all `tf.Tensor` values in a loop. How can I do that?

Apparently, some needs a dictionary to be defined:

```
sess.run('MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/Relu6:0')
```

For example:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype float and shape [?,128,128,3]
     [[Node: input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,128,128,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request the value of a tensor, Tensorflow computes that value in the graph as tensor values are not usually retained across different calls to `sess.run` (that's what variables are for). It seems like the operations necessary to compute the value of the tensor you requested need input from one of your input placeholders (named `input` in the error statement), thus you must feed a value for that placeholder through the feed dictionary in `sess.run`.

Following your comment, consider this example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(4)
b = tf.constant(3)
c = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [], 'c')

d = a + b
e = a + c
```

Requesting tensor `d` works fine:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(d))  # prints 7
```

However, requesting `e` throws the same error you report:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(e))
```

which prints

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'c' with dtype int32
     [[Node: c = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

This happens because in order to evaluate `e` we must compute `a + c` and if we don't feed a value to `c`, this is not possible. So, e.g., this works:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(e, feed_dict={c: 1}))  # prints 5
```

Evaluating `d` worked fine because the computation path necessary to evaluate `d` does not involve a placeholder. So, to fix your problem, you should feed a value for the placeholder called `'input'` in your call to `sess.run('MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_pointwise/Relu6:0')`.

Comment: can you be more specific and give an MWE?